# Mongo DB find() query error

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB.  I have a collection called `person`. I'm trying to get all the records without an `_id` field with this query:

```
db.person.find({}{_id:0})
```

but the error is

> syntax error: unexpected {

but if i write

```
db.person.find()
```

it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following documents inserted in `person` collection as

```
db.person.insert({"name":"abc"})
db.person.insert({"name":"xyz"}
```

If you want to find exact matching then use query as

```
db.person.find({"name":"abc"})
```

this return only matched `name` documents

If you want all `names` without `_id` then use [projeciton](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) id query as

```
db.person.find({},{"_id":0})
```

which return

```
{ "name" : "abc" }
{ "name" : "xyz" }
```

Comment: yes, I want the person names without the _id field. and thats why i wrote the query db.person.find({},{"_id":0}) but did not work

Comment: ahh, i found the error, i missed the comma(,) . sorry

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mongodb manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) you have little wrong syntax, you forgot to give comma after  `{}`

Try this :

```
db.person.find({}, { _id: 0 } )
```

Comment: i Want all the person without _id field , but as far as i know, your query will try to find the person with  _id:0 .

Comment: Oh, ok, its little unclear from question that you dont want `_id`, modified my answer, now it will work, you forgot the comma ;)